# Heatmapjs "h337" is unknown when h337.create(config); gets exexuted with AngularJS app; Unknown provider: h337Provider - in angular js

Tags: angularjs, typescript, heatmap

When I used `var heatmapInstance = h337.create(config);` I am getting following error in heatmap.js.

`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: h337Provider`

Heat map component code,

```
export class HeatMapComponent extends BaseComponent {
        constructor() {
            super("heatMapComponent");

            this.templateUrl = "app/app-components/app-heat-map/HeatMap.View.html";
            this.controller = heatMapController;
            this.properties = {
                heatMapData: com.dashboard.core.ScopeType.equalScope
            }
            this.replace = true;
        }

        public init(scope: any, element: any, attr?: any, ctrl?: any): void {

            var config = {
                container: document.getElementById("container"),
                radius: 10,
                maxOpacity: .5,
                minOpacity: 0,
                blur: .75
            };

            var heatmapInstance = h337.create(config);
            heatmapInstance.setData(scope.vm.heatMapData);
        }
    }
```

template:

```
<div id="container">
    <canvas id="heatMap"></canvas>
</div>
```

As I guess this results from the `$injector` being unable to resolve a required dependency. 
So what are the dependencies that should be injected?

I have used typescript and compiled it to angular js.

Comment: how do you include heatmap.js in your module ?

Comment: Usually this error happen when the items you're injecting has different nam or needs to be configured in confog phase. Anyway it would be usefull to see the code to spot the error

Comment: It's bit had to point out the exact issue without a code snippet. What you are guessing is correct. Maybe you have loaded files in wrong order.

Comment: @ MayK - I have included heatmap.js through bower and gulp task will bind scripts to index file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable (`declare var h337: any;`) at global scope. This is done in order to let typescript compiler, there will be a reference available at run time.